# Error in using Style Tag of MUI with styled-component and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I created SelectType component using Styled Component as follows:

```
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

export const SelectType = styled(Select)`
    width:100%;
    border:2px solid #eaeaef;
    border-radius:8px;
    margin-top:2px;
    /* padding:8px; */
`
```

Then I am using it as follows:

```
 <SelectType
     value={dataFieldType}
     placeholder="Select Data Field Type"
     onChange={handleSelect}
 >
    <MenuItem value={"address"}>Address</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"number"}>Number</MenuItem>
 </SelectType>
```

handleSelect function is as follows:

```
 const handleSelect = (e:SelectChangeEvent) => {
       setDataFieldType(e.target.value as string)
 }
```

But onChange is showing this error:

*No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { input?: ReactElement<any, any> | undefined; label?: ReactNode; slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; title?: string | undefined; ... 292 more ...; variant?: "filled" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.*

If I am directly using *Select* from MUI, it is working fine but throwing error for *SelectType*

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you fix this?

Comment: I have switched to Reach-select. Its more user friendly and provides nice features out of the box. If your app uses dropdown a lot, its worth switching to [this](https://react-select.com/home)

Comment: Check my answer. Thats how i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<unknown>` like this:

```
const handleSelect = (event: SelectChangeEvent<unknown>) => {
    setDataFieldType(event.target.value as string);
  };
```

Hope this helps.